# C++: How to force XCode 7.2.1 to ignore redefinitions that are causing errors

Tags: c++, xcode, compiler-errors, xcode7, adobe-indesign

I have a project that builds just fine in Release Mode but Debug Mode shows many `Redefinition` errors at compile time. As shown in the snapshot attached.[Error Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhbSo.png)

Is there any way that can force XCode to just ignore these errors?

**Update:**

I know it's not the right way to go but I just want to know if it can be done or not.

**UPDATE-2:**

The redefinition was due to a redundant `.pch` file. I have solved this issue.

Comment: Why not try and *fix* the errors instead of just silencing them?

Comment: Fix the redefinitions in 1st place1

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Because they are not redefined anywhere else. I don't know whats going on here but silencing them would make the build successful.

Comment: @d0mbn00b ‘*Because they are not redefined anywhere else.*’ You think the compiler just made that up?

Comment: Without being able to see the full error messages (why don't you get a text-view of the build output, and copy-paste it into the question body as you should (please [read about how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask))) it's hard to tell, but usually you will get a message saying *where* the first definition was. That way you should be able to find out how the two definitions differ and a possible way to fix it.

Comment: @Biffen No no. There's definitely something going on. Compiler didn't made that up. But as far as this project goes these variables are not defined anywhere else. Because I couldn't find them anywhere, except this one file where the errors are.

Comment: @d0mbn00b My guess is that that file gets included more than once, with some preprocessor variables having different values.

Comment: @Biffen There's `#pragma once` in the header file.

Comment: @d0mbn00b Yes. That doesn't mean it can't be included by multiple compilation units.

Comment: @d0mbn00b `#pragma once` or other header include guard only protects against multiple inclusion in the same [*translation unit*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_unit_(programming)). If two or more source files include a header file where variables are defined you will get multiple definition errors.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Okay! I didn't know that. Thank you.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude The redefinition was due to a redundant `.pch` file. I have solved this issue.